# Ввод массива структур в функцию

Tags: структуры, c++

Никак не получется ввести массив структур в функцию. Что я нашёл:

> Чтобы управлять массивом из функции, ей достаточно знать указатель на первый элемент массива, нужно объявить функцию так
>
> `get_mass(F* b) // где b и есть тот самый указатель`
>
> Теперь вызывать функцию надо так, чтобы она получала этот самый указатель на первый элемент
>
> `get_mass(&b[0]); // либо попросту get_mass(in,b);`

Но как дальше из функции обращаться к элементам этого массива структур? К примеру `b[2]->books` не проходит, выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Еще один хитрый трюк. В опредление структуры можно добавить указатель на следующий элемент и тем самым получить связный список.

Comment: Это ещё зачем?

Comment: @klopp, видимо @igumnov начал осваивать списки, восхищается гибкостью этой структуры данных и советует остальным не проходить мимо.

Comment: Кстати, о терминах.

@Игорь, обычно говорят о *передаче структур в функцию*. 

Термин *ввод* обычно подразумевает заполнение структуры из **внешнего** источника (файл, терминал, может быть диалоговое окно).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное так

```
struct x {
  int f1, f2;
};

void pri(struct x *array, int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("sum[%d] = %d\n",i,
            array[i].f1+array[i].f2); // видимо это вызывало затруднения
}
main ()
{
   struct x a[] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
   pri (a,3);
}
```

Comment: Да, именно это. Странно, а разве мы не должны использовать array[i]->f1, ведь мы передаем ссылку на структуру.

Comment: Стрелка была бы в такой конструкции (по смыслу равнозначна приведённой, с []):

        printf ("sum[%d] = %d\n",i,      
            (array+i)->f1+(array+i)->f2);

Comment: Мы передаем указатель на структуру. Это синтаксически эквивалентно массиву. 

В Си массив всегда передается в функцию в виде указателя, другими словами адреса первого элемента массива.

Запись `array[i]->f1` соответствует случаю передачи массива указателей на структуры. Т.е.

    f(struct x *a[]) { // можно написать и так f(struct x **a)
       return a[2]->f1 + a[3]->f2; 
    }
    main() {
      struct x *a[4], s1 = {2,3}, s2 = {4,5};
      a[2] = &s1; a[3] = &s2;
      printf ("%d\n",f(a)); // сумма s1.f1 и s2.f2 
    }